# Why IllegalArgumentException (JDK 1.4.2) cannot be constructed with a throwable cause?

Tags: java, exception

From a class extending java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport :

```
/**
 * Sets the property value by parsing a given String.  May raise
 * java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if either the String is
 * badly formatted or if this kind of property can't be expressed
 * as text.
 *
 * @param text  The string to be parsed.
 */
public void setAsText(String name) {
    try {
        asEnum(name);
    } catch (InvalidEnumNameException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to convert value: "+ name);
    }
}
```

will cause the true stack trace to be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IllegalArgumentException [*does* have constructors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html#IllegalArgumentException(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) that take a `Throwable` `cause` parameter - that code simply doesn't use them, possibly because it is older than the "Exceptions have a `Throwable` `cause`" convention, which was introduced with Java 5.

Comment: In that case you're out of luck - the cause parameter was not present in most (all?) Exceptions before 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Use [initCause](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)):

```
try {
  throw new IOException();
} catch (IOException e) {
  IllegalStateException ise = new IllegalStateException();
  ise.initCause(e);
  throw ise;
}
```

Not as pleasant, but will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a curious omission. Generally it's used like this:

```
if (value == null) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value can't be null");
}
```

But as you've demonstrated there are occasions where taking an exception would be useful. One of those quirks that makes Java *so* fun. In the above I'd simply extract the exception message. The context should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Java SE 5, IllegalArgumentException did not accept a Throwable cause.
In Java SE 5 and later, it does.